# Pegar nome de class e ID jquery

Tags: jquery

Galera tenho a seguinte situação, faço um busca em um objeto atras de algumas classes, como sabemos o FIND() retorna o que está dentro da classe selecionada, utilizo juntamento com o find o each, percorrendo todo o objeto.

Mas a situação que tenho, devo listar todos (IDs e classes) descendentes das classes do find, eu tenho que listar o nome dessas classes e dos ids:

```
$(objeto).find('.nome1, .nome2').each(function(index, value){


});
```

Imagina, se tiver algum ID (id="meunome" ou class="teste" etc) eu tenho que listar tudo isso, eu não tenho ideia de quantos elementos descendentes possuí, eu não sei o nome de todos, pois são mais de 100 paginas WEB dentro do objeto...

Eu sei que se eu soube-se o tipo de elemento, eu poderia fazer:

```
$(this).attr('id');
$(this).attr('class');
```

O que preciso é verificar quais os nomes das classes e dos IDs que tenho no objeto... de onde fiz a busca com find...

Alguém tem um rumo para eu fazer isso...

Comment: .nome1 e .nome2 são fixos ou você desconhece?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O "*" busca tudo.

Se vc desconhece as classes:

```
var arrayObjetos = [];

$(objeto).find('*').each(function(){
    var classe = $(this).attr("class");
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    arrayObjetos .push({classe:classe, id:id});
});
```

Se vc quiser filtrar mesmo pelos classes .nome1 e .nome2:

```
var arrayObjetos = [];

$(objeto).find('.nome1 *, .nome2 *').each(function(){
    var classe = $(this).attr("class");
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    arrayObjetos .push({classe:classe, id:id});
});
```

Por fim no console você vê o resultado:

```
console.log(arrayObjetos);
```

Comment: Não tem necessidade de criar novos objetos jquery para pegar essas propriedades, melhor usar direto `this.id` e `this.className`

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo.. Eu realmente não ""conhecia"" o *, na realidade a utilidade dele no Jquery...  Era só pensar no reset do `CSS (*)` ... `Mysql SELECT *`...  ATT

Comment: Verdade @bfavaretto, acostumei com jQuery e certos comandos js puro eu não sei de cabeça mesmo, mas ótima dica.